# Cron to move data's from one database to another in laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, database, cron, laravel-5

I want to run a cron yearly where I need to move all the data's from one database to another database using laravel 5.2. And here, I am using mySql database. I searched in laravel 5.2 documentation, but all I could find is that, database migration is used to move data from one database to another one and that too through terminal commands. How can I achieve this through laravel 5.2 code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please leave a comment for down vote. I didnt get .

Answer (score 0):

On the following path:

```
your_project/app/Console/Commands
```

make a schedule command to run on cron. In this command make function that take the database dump from DB1 and put the backup to some other database say DB2.

For this, you have to make connection with two database, [read this](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections) to connect with more than one databse.

[Laravel Scheduler Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling)

Comment: Thanks Mayank... Let me try this.

Comment: I don't know why peoples down-vote and do not tell the reason in comment

Comment: Sorry for the delay caused. Actually, I couldnt find the query to move data from one database to another one and the call to the scheduler didnt work properly.

Comment: I am not getting you ?

Comment: how can I write query to move all data's from one database to another database. While searching I could only find sql commands

Comment: So what do you wants ?

Comment: Hi Mayank.. could u please give me the reference links for this question that u were posted in chat room ???

Comment: Which reference link are you talking about ?

Comment: the links that you were posted , php code to copy data's from one database to another

Comment: Did you save that chat link? If not, give me your email id if possible ?

Comment: Mayank .. are u able to access this https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149771/laravel-5-2-and-mysqldump-and-restore

Comment: @Rose Yes, I have joined the chat room